# How to add folder struture in web deployment project

Tags: asp.net, deployment, project

I am trying to create a web deployment project for a web appplication that requires a directory structure to be created somewhere in the file system (user choice). This structure could be placed anywhere and does not need to be inside the project folder.

How can I set the project to allow the user to define the root where this directoy structure will be installed?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it, giving the user access to choose any file system location could be a little too much access. Unless this is something where the user already has direct access to the server, I don't see the benefit over making it a sub-folder of the project.

If you still think that you want them to choose an arbitrary location, it is not that complicated. When the user first runs the project, it asks for the directory to store the files. That directory is initialized with whatever it needs and then you store a small file in the project directory that tells you what folder the user chose. Then you read in the value to do subsequent runs.

Comment: Thank you for the input, I think I wasn't clear enought. I have a web site AND a directory structure(separated from the web project). It is this directory structure that I need to allow the user to define, works apart from the website.